# Assign URL to every form that is submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have the form and when the user submits the form, the information is stored inside the MySQL database. I want it so that when the user submits the form, it will give that form a URL with the information that they submitted on that form. I need a unique URL for each form that is submitted. When I go to that URL, the information from that form is displayed. How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you possibly need that? I think there's a good chance you're over thinking your solution.

Comment: Show us some code you already have so we can simply tell you what to change, not write complete code. We are lazy too ;)

Comment: Try removing the `post` or `get` from `<form>` `method`..ie `<form action="your_action" method="">`..you'll get all your inserted values as querystrings in the other page..

Comment: tell me if you have any doubts regarding it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer & Demo

> ---
>
> I've setup a [**php demo**](http://butler.tk/form.htm) so you can see what the following code does.
>
> (Note: If you are viewing this post later the demo may be offline, as it's a personal free website I use and could be disconnected)
>
> ---

You can do what (i think) you want by assigning an id to each form you save in the table, and then creating another `.php page` that will get the form data of the form whose id equals x id.

So, let's say you save a form with:

- **name** : Lucas
- **description** : Lucas is a great guy.

You would also automatically save:

- **id** : 21894128947

And then you would get the form info via this url:

> http://www.somewebsite.com/getform.php?id=21894128947

### HTML (form.htm)

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Description:<textarea name="description"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

It's a simple `form` with two `input` elements and a submit button. You may change this to whatever input's you need.

### PHP (process.php)

```
<?php
    $servername = "mysqlhost";
    $username = "mysqluser";
    $password = "mysqlpass";
    $dbname = "mysqldatabasename";
        $id = rand(0,100000000);
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $description = $_POST["description"];
        $url = "../getform.php?id=".$id;

    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO someTable (id,name, description) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$description."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$url."</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

We assign an **id** (a random number between 0 and 1000000000) for the form, and we get the **name** from the `$_POST["name"]` variable, and the **description** `$_POST["description"]`variable.

> The syntax is $_POST["**n**"] where *n* is the name you assigned the element in the `HTML`.

We then create a mysql connection and push the values id,name,description into the table fields id,name,description.

> The syntax is "INSERT INTO **table** (**field**,**field**,**field**) VALUES ('**value**','**value**','**value**')" where **table** is the table name, **field** is the table field name, and **value** is the value you want to push in that field.

Then we `echo` or print a link to the custom form url, wich would be handled by the `getform.php` file.

### SQL TABLE (in phpMyAdmin)

[image: SQL Table (in phpMyAdmin)]

Here is how the sql table would look like in my server's phpMyAdmin. (You should create this table in order for the code work)

### PHP (getform.php)

```
<?php
    $servername = "mysqlhost";
    $username = "mysqluser";
    $password = "mysqlpass";
    $dbname = "mysqldatabasename";
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " .$row["id"]. "<br>";
            echo "name:  ".$row["name"]."<br>";
            echo "description: ".$row["description"]."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results with that id";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

We connect to the database, we get the **id** form the `$_GET["id"]` variable, which works almost exactly like the $_POST one, but using the `get method` in your `form`.

Then we select the specific row containing our form data filtering by id, the syntax for that is:

> "SELECT * FROM **table** WHERE id = **id**" where **table** is the table name, and id is the id provided in the `get request`.

Then, we get the result of the query via `Connection->query(sql)` where **sql** is the actual query.

Then we check if there number of rows selected is bigger than 0, and then we iterate over every row using `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` where **$row** is an array containing each field of the table and it's value.

Finally we use the following syntax to get the value of a field:

> $row["**field**"]

where **field** is the field name.

---

Hope this helps man, sorry if I didn't get what you wanted to do :)

Comment: Wow, if I can give you more than a "check", I would. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciation it's enough, good luck :)

Comment: Thank you again Rou! Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I explain what you need with an example:

Suppose the form submit information about an article(you need article table in database too) so every time a user submit form, new row in article table inserted with unique id.

Then for showing this article(this is what you want in your question: unique URL for each form that is submitted) use url like this: showArticle.php?id=(pu article id here)